# How to restrict the vocabulary size of an LSTM?

Tags: python, nlp, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I want to have a model that only predicts a certain syntactic category, for example verbs, can I update the weights of the LSTM so that they are set to 1 if the word is a verb and 0 if it is any other category?

This is my current code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, input_length=5, weights=[pretrained_weights]))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=embedding_size)))
model.add(Dense(2000, activation='softmax'))

for e in zip(model.layers[-1].trainable_weights, model.layers[-1].get_weights()):
    print('Param %s:\n%s' % (e[0], e[1]))

weights = [layer.get_weights() for layer in model.layers]
print(weights)

print(model.summary())

# compile network
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.001),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit network
history = model.fit(X_train_fit, y_train_fit, epochs=100, verbose=2, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))
score = model.evaluate(x=X_test, y=y_test, batch_size=32)
```

These are the weights that I am returning:

```
Param <tf.Variable 'dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(600, 2000) dtype=float32_ref>:
[[-0.00803087  0.0332068  -0.02052244 ...  0.03497869  0.04023124
  -0.02789269]
 [-0.02439511  0.02649114  0.00163587 ... -0.01433908  0.00598045
   0.00556619]
 [-0.01622458 -0.02026448  0.02620039 ...  0.03154427  0.00676246
   0.00236203]
 ...
 [-0.00233192  0.02012364 -0.01562861 ... -0.01857186 -0.02323328
   0.01365903]
 [-0.02556716  0.02962652  0.02400535 ... -0.01870854 -0.04620285
  -0.02111554]
 [ 0.01415684 -0.00216265  0.03434955 ...  0.01771339  0.02930249
   0.002172  ]]
Param <tf.Variable 'dense_1/bias:0' shape=(2000,) dtype=float32_ref>:
[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
[[array([[-0.023167 , -0.0042483, -0.10572  , ...,  0.089398 , -0.0159   ,
         0.14866  ],
       [-0.11112  , -0.0013859, -0.1778   , ...,  0.063374 , -0.12161  ,
         0.039339 ],
       [-0.065334 , -0.093031 , -0.017571 , ...,  0.16642  , -0.13079  ,
         0.035397 ],
```

and so on.
Can I do it by updating the weights? Or is there a more efficient way to be able to only output verbs?
Thank you for the help!

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking.
0. What is the nature of the current model? (what are the inputs and outputs?)
1. Do you have a labeled data: verb/not_verb?
2. In the output layer, is 2000 actually the vocab_size?

Comment: Sorry, it was a little confusing! My question is: is there a way to only predict the verbs? Because when I run the model, the predicted classes are composed mostly of closed classes words, such as 'in', 'all', 'the' and so on! My training set is composed by sentences, my test set is composed by sentences without verbs and my labels are the verbs. I changed the output layer to be the size of the label classes.

Answer (score 0):

In this model, with this loss (categorical_crossentropy), you cannot learn verb/non-verb labels without supervision. So, you need labeled data. Perhaps, you can use tagged corpus, e.g. Penn Tree Bank corpus, train this model which takes the input words and predicts the output labels (closed class of labels).

If you want to have one tag and regression on each word, you can change the model so the last layer becomes a value between 0 and 1:

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Then change the loss function to be a binary:

```
# compile network
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.001),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Then instead of labels, you should have `1` and `0` values in `y_train_fit` representing verb/non-verb of each word.